# Hibernate JPA empty result with correct query

Tags: hibernate, list, jpa, collections, empty-list

Hibernate retrieve returns empty list, while populated list is expected.
Involving 2 objects, mapping done by annotations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
class Child {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
    @OrderBy(value="id")
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Query performed:

```
String queryString = "select c from Child c where c.parent.id = ?1";
Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString);
q.setParameter("1", parentId);
return q.getResultList();
```

When hibernate executes that set of code it returns a list with size = 0. Turning SQL logging on and performing the query provided in the logs in MAMP returns the expected result, any one any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This should fix the problem:

```
q.setParameter(1, parentId);
```

Currently you are calling `Query.setParameter(String, Object)` which is for setting named parameters in the query but you are using a positional parameter in your query. Changing it to `Query.setParameter(int, Object)` will set the positional parameter and the query will work.

Comment: I'm affraid that doesn't resolve the problem, even when i alter the query to something as simple as: "select c from Child c" it still returns an empty list :/ Programmatically the Child database is filled, so it's not a configuration issue either :/

Answer (score 1):

Problem was caused due to transaction management.
We've used @Transactional for Spring to indiciate how to manage transactions. But some of our transaction strategies were wrong.

So who ever comes across this problem should turn on transaction logging to see if the transactions get committed the way you expect them to. To prevent you from accessing data from an transaction which hasn't been committed yet.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you did exactly? Because I am in the middle of a transaction. But it looks like the query is not using the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this import:

```
import javax.persistence.Query
```

you should mention this one:

```
import org.hibernate.Query
```